# Missing customer name/address information in SquareUp Console using Square.Connect.Api

Tags: square-connect

We are creating a Square 2.0 transaction but when we login to our Square account, the customer name/address information is missing.  We are creating a customer address object and populating the properties but they are not showing up in the Square console.

Here is our code:

```
using Square.Connect.Api;
using Square.Connect.Model;
using Square.Connect.Client;



private static bool RunCreditCardSquare(int? adminId, Models.ReservationReceivePaymentViewModel payment, Models.GuestViewModel guest, String ipaddress, String orderdescription, int reservationId, decimal amountDue)
    {
        Data.BigRigEntities db = new Data.BigRigEntities();



        TransactionsApi transactionsApi = new TransactionsApi();
        Square.Connect.Client.Configuration.Default.AccessToken = accessToken;

        string uuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Money amount = new Money((long)amountDue * 100, Money.CurrencyEnum.USD);

        // (https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/transactions/overview#mpt-overview).

        ChargeRequest body = new ChargeRequest(AmountMoney: amount, IdempotencyKey: uuid, CardNonce: payment.CardNonce);
        Square.Connect.Model.Address.CountryEnum GuestCountry = Square.Connect.Model.Address.CountryEnum.US;

        body.ShippingAddress = new Square.Connect.Model.Address(guest.Address1, "", "", guest.City, "", "", "", "", "", "", guest.PostalCode, GuestCountry, guest.FirstName, guest.LastName, "");
        body.BillingAddress =  new Square.Connect.Model.Address(guest.Address1, "", "", guest.City, "", "", "", "", "", "", guest.PostalCode, GuestCountry, guest.FirstName, guest.LastName, "");

        body.ReferenceId = reservationId.ToString() ;
        body.CardNonce = payment.CardNonce;
        body.BuyerEmailAddress = guest.EmailAddress;
        body.Note = "Conf #:" + reservationId.ToString() + " - " + orderdescription;

        var charged = false;
        var transactionid = "";
        var error = "";
        decimal chargeamount = 0.0M;

        try
        {
            var response = transactionsApi.Charge(LocationId, body);
            transactionid = response.Transaction.Id;
            chargeamount = (decimal) (response.Transaction.Tenders[0].AmountMoney.Amount/100) ;  
            charged =  true;
        }
        catch (ApiException e)
        {
            error = e.Message; 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The shipping address and billing address are only available via API, not the Square Dashboard. To see this information attached to a customer in the Dashboard you should [Create a Customer](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-createcustomer) first and then pass the `customer_id` along when you charge.